# is there a good way to record something streamed using winamp?

Tags: recording, winamp, streaming

If I have streaming audio/video files that are viewed through winamp, how could I save the stream? It can't be viewed in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Streamripper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamripper/files/streamripper%20%28current%29/) records shoutcast-compatible streams. For shoutcast style streams it finds the "meta data" or track separation data, and uses that as a marker for where the track should be separated.

Another method to save shoutcast streams is to use LAME plugin for Winamp. Just follow the instructions on this [page](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Use_Winamp_shoutcast_23178956) to achieve that.

Comment: streamripper looks like its what I need, but how do I use it under windows? it looks like a linux source package, don't know how to use that in win

Comment: Use [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamripper/files/streamripper%20%28current%29/1.64.6/streamripper-windows-installer-1.64.6.exe/download) link for Windows installer.

Answer (score 1):

haven't experimented with this, but setting the output plug in to diskwriter could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I created an application for this, you can take a look at the demo: http://www.streamsink.com.

It can:

- capture multiple (hundreds) streams at once
- capture reliably 24/7
- capture mp3, aacplus, wma (has wmv capturing but it's not relevant to this question)

And so on...